# Version of Thom isomorphism theorem for fibers with Poincaré duality

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles, poincare-duality

Let $F$ be a path-connected [Poincaré duality space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Poincar%C3%A9+duality+space) (using $\mathbb{Z}$ coefficients for singular co/homology) of dimension $n$. In particular, we have $H^n(F;\mathbb{Z}) \approx \mathbb{Z} \approx H_n(F;\mathbb{Z})$.

Let us say a given map $f : F \rightarrow F$ is orientation-preserving if the induced $f_*$ on $H_n$ is the identity.
Define $\mathrm{Homeo}_+(F)$ to be the subgroup of auto-homeomorphisms of $F$ which are orientation-preserving.

Let $X \xrightarrow{\pi} Y$ be a continuous fiber bundle with fiber $F$. For $y\in Y$ we use the notation $X_y := \pi^{-1}(y)$.

We make the following definitions:

- We say $\pi$ is fiber-orientable if $Y$ admits a covering by local trivializations $\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha) \xrightarrow{\approx} U_\alpha \times F$ such that the transition maps $\phi_\beta(U_\alpha) \times F \rightarrow \phi_\alpha(U_\beta) \times F$ can be viewed as maps $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta \rightarrow \mathrm{Homeo}_+(F)$.
- We say a given $c \in H^n(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is a Thom class for $\pi$ if for every $y\in Y$ the pulled-back class $c|_{X_y} \in H^n(X_y;\mathbb{Z})$ is a generator.

---

Under the above conditions, is there a Thom isomorphism -like theorem which says the following?

1. The fiber bundle $\pi$ is fiber-orientable iff it admits a Thom class.
2. If $c$ is a Thom class, then
   $$
   \begin{matrix}
   H^j(Y;\mathbb{Z}) & \rightarrow & H^{j+n}(X;\mathbb{Z}) \\
   a &\mapsto&  c \smile  (\pi^*a)
   \end{matrix}
   $$
   is an isomorphism for each integer $j\geq0$.

Comment: You are a little mixed up. The Thom isomorphism should be applied to bundles with fiber either $\mathbb{R}^n$ or $S^n$. If you are talking about general fiber bundles, then the total space will typically have more cohomology than the base if it is orientable. This is not to say that fiber bundles or fibrations with Poincare duality fiber are uninteresting.

Comment: @ConnorMalin I see, thank you! Then, instead of a Thom isomorphism, do we instead have some sort of "Künneth-like" theorem about the cohomology of the total space in terms of the fiber and base?

Comment: There is kind of an analogue of Thom isomorphism for fiber bundles which is called Leray-Hirsch which could sometimes, but not usually hold. As always, there is the Serre spectral sequence which is like a Kunneth theorem. Neither of these use the Poincare duality though. You might be familiar with a process called integration along the fiber, this is usually defined for manifold bundles, but it also exists for Poincare duality bundles.

Comment: @ConnorMalin I see, thanks for your explanation!